# Can I install 12.10 on an external HD that will become an internal drive in another system without changing my Windows 7 system?

Tags: installation, external-hdd

How can I install 12.10 on an external hard drive that I plan to put into another computer that will only run Ubuntu?  I have this drive connected to my Windows 7 and the reason I'm asking is because I have tried to install from the DVD directly into this other computer without luck as the install errors out halfway through the install.  The details on the error messages are all very cryptic so I won't bother to include them - I just need to know how to install on this now external drive that will soon be the primary drive for this other computer without hosing up my Win 7 box as I don't want that machine to become a dual booter.  Please help!  Also I almost forgot - the HD I'm installing on (that I removed from the other computer is IDE - could this be the problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if IDE could be a problem but try to install from boot menu using advanced tools and create the boot partition in the external hard drive. This might solve the problem.